# Communicating with the LPT port through USB adapter

Tags: usb, port, adapter, parallel-port, lpt

I have a proprietary hardware which accepts input on the parallel port. The problem is the PC which needs to communicate with the hardware doesn't have a parallel port and I can't change it's configuration.

I have an USB to LPT adapter, but the adapter doesn't emulate the LPT port. Even with the driver installed, it shows as "USB Parallel Bridge" in Control Panel.

The hardware expects input on the data ports D0-D7 of the LPT. Can I send this kind of data through the USB port of the adapter? How?

If not, can I create a virtual LPT? The PC is running Windows 7.

Most of the questions I saw asked around here were targeted at printers, so their solutions don't apply to my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Most USB adapters won't do for advanced parallel port operation. They are made only for printers.

Fortunately, interface cards are still available, even for PCI Express slots. This is what I'd suggest. A fair warning though: I haven't actually used such an interface yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes such devices exist, however they are very expensive compared to the printer only adapters.

But you can end up facing other issues (like we have) as in there is no raw access to LPT data registers after Windows 98, which we worked around at the time via a driver that allowed access. However Windows7 64-bit does not like unsigned drivers like the one we have so we are kind of stuck again with how to continue supporting our LPT-interfaced hardware.

Comment: Hi! Could you please suggest some adapters which offer LPT virtualization? Or could you tell me which one you've used? Just so I know what the options are... Thank you!

Comment: Not really since I can't seem to find any from our suppliers anymore, and I will be out of office for a week so I won't be able to quickly look at what we have. What you need to look for is something that has the full interface, they cost around 150€.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is to install a 'real' parallel port using expresscard:

[https://www.amazon.com/SIIG-USB-to-ExpressCard-JU-EP0012-S1/dp/B001KUOW9O/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KUOW9O)

[image]

Combined with [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-ExpressCard-Parallel-Adapter-EC1PECPS/dp/B001Q7X0W6/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001Q7X0W6)

[image]

But this may or may not have massive driver problems depending on the exact setup with your system.  Best of luck!

Comment: Would that even work? The USB/ExpressCard adapter of course does not support PCIe connectivity. From the card's description, I guess it uses PCI Express, not USB.